# procmailrc recipe: turn on VERBOSE conditionally?

Tags: procmail

I would like a recipe for my procmailrc file to turn on VERBOSE only if an e-mail came in from one (and only one) particular e-mail address.  My procmail spam filter is way too long (and old) and difficult to go over each individual line.

Comment: What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What does your config look like? Do you have any log entries from the times it didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question could use more details, but what you are asking is simple enough.

```
:0
* ^From:(.*\<)?donaldjtrump@trump\.com\>
{ VERBOSE=yes }
```

The braces are necessary because the assignment is not an action. The regex in the condition obviously needs to be replaced with one which uniquely identifies messages from your specific evil clown villain.